# Why isn't the function declared in the prototype called?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

```
var p = function () {
    this.show = function () {
       alert('hello world!!!');
    }
}

p.prototype.show = function() {
    alert('haha');
}

var o  = new p();
o.show();
```

It alerts `"hello world!!!"`, why?

Can I modify prototype method, if yes how?

Comment: A very thorough explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript

Comment: FYI: You can call the prototype method if you need to: `p.prototype.show.call(o)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the specific function you define in the constructor overrides the one that is inherited through the prototype.

From [EcmaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.2.1) :

> Every object created by a constructor has an implicit reference
>   (called the object’s prototype) to the value of its constructor’s
>   “prototype” property. Furthermore, a prototype may have a non-null
>   implicit reference to its prototype, and so on; this is called the
>   prototype chain. When a reference is made to a property in an object,
>   that reference is to the property of that name in the first object in
>   the prototype chain that contains a property of that name. In other
>   words, first the object mentioned directly is examined for such a
>   property; if that object contains the named property, that is the
>   property to which the reference refers; if that object does not
>   contain the named property, the prototype for that object is examined
>   next; and so on.

In short : when looking for a function (or any property by its name), you start at the object and then go up in the prototype chain.

Answer (score 3):

You override your `prototype.show` method in `p` function.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript when a property is resolved the engine first looks at the properties of an object.  In your example the object would be represented by `this`.  If it finds the property, in this case `show` (Remember functions can be properties) it uses that property.  If the property is not found it then iterates down the prototype chain in an effort to resolve the property.